# Convert the day time on python

Tags: python, api, datetime, google-calendar-api

I have a question based on the conversion of a date and time using the start_time element's Google Calendar API, how could I convert it to a day, month and year of Latin America without more, if you could help me please
the datetime:
2021-01-19T09:00:00-05:00
I need the follow example:  day/mount/year 15/01/2021
I've been trying and can't find a way to convert properly, please if you could help me.

Comment: use ```datetime.strptime()``` and ```datetime.strftime()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `datetime` library:

```py
import datetime

date_str = "2021-01-19T09:00:00-05:00"
date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str[:10], "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

print(date_obj)
```

Comment: Excuse me my friend and to obtain the hour and minutes, the formatting for the aforementioned could be attached in the same way, right?

Comment: @Dash166, Yes, I would also recommend checking out [strftime.org](https://strftime.org)

Comment: @Dash166 You can use `date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z").strftime("%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")`